# Why does `{1: Infinity, 1000: Infinity}` => `{0: NaN, 1: Infinity, 2: NaN, 1000: Infinity}` on iOS 10.3.3 Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Why does `{1: Infinity, 1000: Infinity}` => `{0: NaN, 1: Infinity, 2: NaN, 1000: Infinity}`?

In debugging an issue I came across this as the root cause of a bug but still not sure why this is happening. Have only been able to reproduce on iOS 10.3.3 on Safari but a small (but significant) chunk of our users are experiencing the same issue.

Here is a screenshot of some results while debugging remotely on Safari:

[JS Weirdness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn1fk.png)

Comment: That definitely *shouldn't* happen, and does not happen in Chrome. It looks like `0..n-1` numerical properties *prior* to the `n: Infinity` are being filled in with NaN which smells like an Array-impl bleed. What happens if replacing `1000` with a non-integer key? What about with a *very large integer*? (Similar for the first `n` key..)

Comment: And, does using explicit post-literal property assignment avoid the issue? `x = {}; x[1] = Infinity; x[1000] = Infinity; x`

Comment: Also, does the original "bad" object created have a `length` property set? (If so, it would be a "smoking gun" as to some Array-impl mixup.)

Comment: @user2864740: It does not occur with any non-integer key. That said is does still occur with `{"1": Infinity, "1000": Infinity}`. The only patterns I can discern are: 1) values must be Infinity and 2) last key must be `1000` or `"1000"`.

Comment: Please show an actual, complete code example that demonstrates the problem. I can't tell if this is limited to a weird console display or if this is actual faulty data. Showing a console display doesn't tell us enough.

Comment: @user2864740: post-literal property assignment does not avoid the issue (this is actually how we discovered the issue) and `length` is `undefined`.

Comment: Sure does weird stuff in firefox console but Object.keys.length is only 2

Comment: Here is a more complete test showing that this is not a console display issue: [Imgur Link](https://imgur.com/a/UywuE).